# Is it true that when scrolling to the end offsetHeight + scrollTop == scrollHeight?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an infinite scroll component in react. I check (**offsetHeight + scrollTop == scrollHeight**) to realize scrolled to the end. However, when scrolling to the end sometimes **offsetHeight** + **scrollTop** is not equal to **scrollHeight**.

```
  const handleScroll = async (e) => {
    const { offsetHeight, scrollTop, scrollHeight } = e.target;
    console.log(offsetHeight + scrollTop + " ==  " + scrollHeight);
    if (offsetHeight + scrollTop == scrollHeight) {
      console.log("ok");
      setStep((prev) => prev + step);
      fetchData(nowStep + step);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div
      onScroll={handleScroll}
      style={{
        height: height,
        overflowY: "scroll",
        overflowX: "hidden",
        width: "100%",
        padding: 0,
        margin: 0,
        textAlign: "center",
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
```

Here's what I think:

[image]

Edit: I realized the browser zoom could be the cause. At some zoom levels eg: 125%, 100%, 75%, 67% the code runs fine, but at 110%, 90%, 80%, the check results are not as expected.
Console when scrolling to the end:

- 110% zoom browser:

```
690.9090881347656 ==  696
694.5454406738281 ==  696
695.757568359375 ==  696
```

- 100% zoom browser:

```
694.6666564941406 ==  696
695.3333435058594 ==  696
696 ==  696
ok
```

- 90% zoom browser:

```
694.0740966796875 ==  696
694.8148498535156 ==  696
695.5555725097656 ==  696
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things. You can achieve an endless scrolling much easier with [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

With IO you can observe an element and react whenever it intersects with either the viewport or another element. For your case you want it to trigger a function whenever it comes into view (intersects with the viewport)

You create a dummy-div at the bottom of your Page and create an IO. Then you just wait for it to come into view and do your logic for adding more items:

```js
let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      addAnotherRow();
    }
  })

});

const target = document.querySelector('#dummy');

observer.observe(target);

addAnotherRow = () => {
  const template = document.querySelector('#moreItem');
  const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);

  document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
ul {
  min-height: 110vh;
}

li {
  min-height: 47vh;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> Test </li>
  <li> Item </li>
  <li> More Content </li>
</ul>

<div id="dummy"> </div>

<template id="moreItem">
<li> Lazy Loaded items </li>
</template>
```